# What are the necessary requirements for coding decimal to binary [Python]?

Tags: python, binary

Okay, so I have had some help with some fellow users on this website and I found you can't just ask someone for code. I am not. I want to know some of the variables and stuff needed to code.

1) Need to have a raw_input so the user can type in their number.
- I have seen you type:

```
raw_input("Please insert a number: ") #This allows you the user to type in a number.
```

2) Need to have if, elif and else statements in my code to stop the user from typing in **Anything but numerical values**

-I think you need this:

```
if raw_input == '£' or '$' or '%' ETC
```

but I think that might take too long :( **Need help to make my if statements**

3) Need to stop the user from entering a value below 1 and above 256.

I think you need this:

```
if raw_input > 256:
     return("Enter a value below 256")
elif raw_input < 1: return("Enter a value above 1")
```

4) Need to have the binary number presented as an '8 bit'

- Example "00000111" same as "111".

Thanks, all information will be useful and I will try to reply to all of yous! Thanks!!!

Comment: This is a beginner question, but one I think may actually be still on-topic. I'll see if I can help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to see if you can help :P

Comment: It seems that the task is overwhelming for you. Don't try to do all at once. You've already splitted it into 4 subtasks that is good. Start with the first one: "how do I get any input from a user?" then move to the second: "how do I get a number from a user and reject a non-numeric input?" Create the code that does nothing but the first task. Make sure that it works. Using the solution for the 1st task, try to do the 2nd one. Otherwise people will just provide a complete solution for you (the whole problem is simple) without any chance for you to understand it.

Comment: I am a quick learner and as soon as I understand some of the values. THANKS!!!!

Comment: What is the function I need to reject ALL inputs, except numerical values :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you've been burned on questions in the past, and probably rightly so. This site is not typically well-suited for rank amateurs, who are better suited looking up a tutorial or reading documentation.

That said, you seem earnest in your efforts and have phrased the question in a meaningful way, so let me try to help:

#### 1) Need to have a raw_input so the user can type in their number

That's correct, the way you store user input in Python2 is `raw_input`, as such:

```
variable_name = raw_input("Prompt")
```

#### 2 and 3) Input validation

Basically both these points are the same -- how do I make sure my user entered data that's appropriate? There's lots of schools of thought on this, and you should read the difference between EAFP and LBYL coding, as well as concepts like duck-typing and etc. For now, let me just show you what *I* would do.

```
number = raw_input("prompt")
try:
    number = int(number)
except ValueError:
    # the user entered a value that can't be converted
    # to an integer, e.g. letters or a decimal number
    # so you'd handle that here, maybe with...
    print("Invalid number")
if 1 <= number <= 255:
    # user has entered a number below 1 or above 256
    # handle it as above, probably ending with:
    return
```

#### 4) Conversion and return of value

Once you've done all the steps above, your number is GUARANTEED to either have thrown an error or be an integer between 1-256. From this point on, it's smooth sailing, just return the binary representation of that number (which is done with the built-in `bin`)

```
else:
    # number is now an integer between 1-256
    return bin(number) # bin(x) returns the number in base 2
```

#### Clarification

There are some terms here you've never seen before, so let me explain.

```
try:
    do_a_thing()
except Exception:
    handle_exception()
```

This is called a `try/except` block, and you use them when you're expecting the thing you're doing inside the block might throw an exception. For instance I might do:

```
try:
    f = open("path/to/a/file.txt", "r") # open a file in read mode
except (IOError,FileNotFoundError,PermissionError):
    print("Can't open that file because of an error")
```

I know when I try to open a file, it might fail if another application has it open, or if I'm not able to access the drive it's on, or even if the file doesn't exist! I then specify underneath how my code should handle each situation, and could even do

```
try:
    f = open("path/to/a/file.txt","r")
except IOError:
    handle_IOError()
except FileNotFoundError:
    make_file("path/to/a/file.txt")
except PermissionError:
    get_permission('path/to/a/file.txt')
```

To handle multiple errors in different ways.

#### Final Product

If this were my code, I would write it like this:

```
def get_binary(value):
    try:
        value = int(value)
        assert 1 >= value >= 255
    except ValueError:
        raise TypeError("Value must be an integer")
    except AssertionError:
        raise ValueError("Value must be between 1-255")
    return bin(value)

user_in = raw_input("Enter a number between 1-255: ")
print "The number in binary is {}".format(get_binary(user_in)[2:])
```

Comment: OMG THANK you so much!!!!! This is perfect. So the:

try, except and if are all in line on the indent? Cool!! Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: I made a couple edits so your code should function exactly as intended in the question :) (changed > to >= and removed the "0b" prefix from the binary numbers)

Comment: @Nathaniel you're welcome. I made a substantial edit to explain `try/except` blocks. Also consider looking up `assert`, which could save you several lines of code.

Comment: Wow, you should replace my current Computing teacher! Thanks for thanks for the information!

Comment: In section 2 I don't think your if statement is correct.

Comment: @Decency whoops, that would be a strange number indeed that is less than `1` and greater than `255`! :)

Answer (score 1):

The basic strategy is to see if you can cast your number appropriately to a float (or int, if you prefer). If you can, it's a valid number. If you can't, ask the user for another input.

```
while (True):
    input = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
    try:
        number = float(input)
        if number < 1 or number > 256:
           print("The number must be between 1 and 256 inclusive.")
           continue
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

# do whatever you want with your number here
print(number)
```

To answer your questions:

- "try" means do something that we think might not work quite right, such as making a number out of something the user is entering that isn't a number. If you do that, it causes a ValueError.
- So, we "except" or "catch" this ValueError. This is where we could do some sort of error handling code, like print("I said a number!").
- continue brings us back to the start of the while loop
- break stops the while look and goes to the next line of code.

Comment: So what does the 'try' mean. Is that the same as 'then'. Also, the 'break' and 'except ValueError'- what does that mean. + Thanks

Comment: I'm going to edit your code to account for the second portion of his statement.

Comment: @Nathaniel Edited with some answers to your questions.

Comment: you edit does not include 1 and 256...also you can do 1<= number <= 256 instead of spreading them out into two statements

Comment: @deweyredman Aware, I feel like this is more explicit and thus more clear. I matched the input validation that the user gave in the OP.

Comment: @Decency For obfuscation purposes, you could do `if number not in range(1,257)`! :)

Comment: @adsmith Continue prompts the user for another input. Break indicates that the input is good and exits the while loop. I don't know what you mean...?

Comment: @Decency Pfft, I missed your `while` loop. I skimmed it and assumed it was a function definition. I've removed my earlier comment.

Comment: @Nathaniel https://www.khanacademy.org/science/computer-science-subject/computer-science/v/while-loops-in-python